# Blank page when visiting site folders

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, indexing, directory

I've just uploaded an open source web-app using 000webhost as hosting provider and can't make it start working.
Basically inside the index.php there's a header that has this function:`

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php 
include_once 'db_functions.php'; 
include_once 'access.php';
if (!userIsLoggedIn()) {
  header('Location: ./src/login.php');
  exit();
```

`

So, it goes to that directory and tries to run the login.php file.
The funny thing is that all I get is a blank page.Every file inside that directory shows up as a blank page.The page-source also shows up as empty!

I tried copying all the files inside the src folder, inside the root and they do work there (when called) but that causes other files to stop working.

I've also changed directory permissions to 777 and still the same problem!

Comment: Check if you can access the error log, or turn on `display_errors` in PHP either through some cpanel, if possible, or in the htaccess-file (only have it on while debugging the issue, though). A blank page is common when there is an error and display errors are turned off. Without an error message, it's impossible for us to know what's wrong.

Comment: Btw, setting the permissions to 777 is bad. Just make sure that the user. and it's group, that runs the web server (like www-data for Apache) has read access to all files and write access to any folder that needs it.

Comment: Your includes are all based on code living in the same directory as the running script. Does everything live in the same directory? It does not according to your `header()`

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is an PHP error, eg. your script is failing at at some point. Server errors could be turned off in the php.ini or your Apache config file.

You can turn it on in the script by adding:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

This will return an error message for you to debug.

Comment: Ok, I did as you suggested and here is the link to the page and the errors showing up!

http://spytest.epizy.com/Monitordroid-Web-Application-master/src/login.php